# How to disable the Power Off timer so that Ubuntu Gnome shuts down immediately when pressing the power button?

Tags: gnome, shutdown, 18.04

Is there a way to disable the power off timer? Or set it to something reasonable like 3 seconds instead of 60?

```
  > lsb_release -a
  LSB Version:  core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
  Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
  Description:  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
  Release:  18.04
  Codename: bionic
```

Comment: Is the tag meant to be `18.04` and not `14.04`?

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `lsb_release -a` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I have edited "lsb_release -a".

Comment: AFAIK there is not **a** power-off timer,  but various scripts that are run on shutdown (in `/etc/rc0.d ` on my 16.04). Several have explicit `sleep` instructions to wait for other parts of the system to stop.